# Parameters of a object get lost (XCode for IPhone)

Tags: string, object, xcode4, parameters, split

I have here a strange behaviour. XCode 4 for iOS 6 (Iphone 4s)
In the init-section I want to read data from a file.

```
NSString *rawData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePathLib encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSArray      *zeilen = [rawData componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
NSLog(@"Check1 \n%@\n%@",rawData, zeilen);
```

OK, now the LogItem shows me, that the correct data were read.

Now I have an if-condition:

```
if ([zeilen count]==4){
        A      = [zeilen objectAtIndex:0];
        B      = [zeilen objectAtIndex:1];
        C      = [zeilen objectAtIndex:2];
        D      =[[zeilen objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
        NSLog(@"Check2 \n%@\n%@ - %@ - %@ - %@ - %d",rawData, zeilen, A, B, C, D);
} else {
        A = @"A0";
        B = @"B0";
        C = @"C0";
        D = 3;
}
```

Now I run this programm.
If the first branch was used, the program crashes, if the second was used, it runs perfectly.
If I use break points I can observe the following:

A   NSString *  0x20063bf0  @"A123"     (the correct value)

B, C, D also correct

later, a line before the crash:

file-read branch:

A, B and C are NOT available, D is correct.

default, branch:

A, B, C and D are correct.

The variables are nowhere else manipulated or even deleted.

Has anyone an idea, where the problem is?

My assumption: The array "zeilen" does not contain NSString-values and therefore they are somehow deleted. But, I do not really believe in this theory, because at the beginning the elements are correct and available and only later they are deleted.

Any idea?

Comment: if I especially add the variables in the "variable viewer" it tells me:
Variable is not NSString (at this position, where formerly the correct value was displayed)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

replace:

```
A      = [zeilen objectAtIndex:0];
```

by

```
A      = [[NSString alloc] stringWithFormat:@"%@",[zeilen objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Memory was not allocated, therefore it got lost.